# Rhythmbox on Ubuntu 16.04 works only with sudo

Tags: rhythmbox

When I try to run rhythmbox as a user it shows:

```
jakub@XenialHP:~$ rhythmbox
Rhythmbox:ERROR:rb-ext-db.c:362:impl_constructor: code should not be reached
Aborted (core dump)
```

<sup>(the last line of the transcript is my translation into English, maybe not the exact message)</sup>

When I try to run it as a root, rhythmbox works well. Reinstalling and purging does not help.

What might be wrong?

Comment: Try closing rhythmbox and then running the following as an ordinary user:  `mv -v ~/.local/share/rhythmbox ~/.local/share/rhythmbox_bak` and then restart rhythmbox.

Comment: Didn't help: jakub@XenialHP:~$ mv -v ~/.local/share/rhythmbox ~/.local/share/rhythmbox_bak
'/home/jakub/.local/share/rhythmbox' -> '/home/jakub/.local/share/rhythmbox_bak'
jakub@XenialHP:~$ rhythmbox
**
Rhythmbox:ERROR:rb-ext-db.c:362:impl_constructor: code should not be reached
Przerwane (zrzut pamięci)
jakub@XenialHP:~$

Comment: More details:
jakub@XenialHP:/etc/apparmor.d$ rhythmbox -d
(12:02:30) [0x7f89dc0056a0] [rb_debug_init_match] rb-debug.c:240: Debugging enabled
(12:02:30) [0x7f89dc0056a0] [construct_db] rb-shell.c:454: creating database object
(12:02:30) [0x7f89dc0056a0] [impl_constructor] rb-ext-db.c:354: creating new metadata store instance album-art
**
Rhythmbox:ERROR:rb-ext-db.c:362:impl_constructor: code should not be reached
Aborted (core dump)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked on GNOME bugzilla and get proper answer:

*Jonathan Matthew [rhythmbox developer]:*

> You apparently don't have permission to create ~/.cache/rhythmbox and you should fix that.  Rhythmbox could probably report the error better, but this has been the error handling mechanism for five years and no one has noticed before.

I used chown /home/jakub/ -R to fix it, and now rhythmbox works well.

Comment: Remember not to use `sudo rhythmbox` in the future; that was the cause of `root` owning your `~/.cache/rhythmbox`.

Comment: I tried to replicate this and it seems to have nothing with sudo: 'ls -al ~/.cache/rhythmbox' shows no chagne after 'sudo rhythmbox'